# Correct way to extend org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body

Tags: java, inheritance, box2d, jbox2d

I'm having a problem trying to extend `org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body`
I've set `Rectangle` to extend `org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body` and set it to be `DYNAMIC`, but the `Rectangle` will not move.
And if I create multiple `Rectangle`'s, they're all positioned in the same position i.e (0.0f, 0.0f), why?

`Rectangle` is defined as:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private PolygonShape blockShape;
    private Body body;
    private float width;
    private float height;

    public Rectangle (
        Vec2 centerPoint, 
        float angle, 
        float width, float height,
        BodyType bt, 
        float density, float friction, float restitution, 
        World world,
        BodyDef bd){

        super(bd,world);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;             

        blockShape = new PolygonShape();
        blockShape.setAsBox(this.width, this.height);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = blockShape;
        fixtureDef.density = density;
        fixtureDef.friction = friction;
        fixtureDef.restitution = restitution;

        this.bodydef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
        this.bodydef.position.set(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
        this.bodydef.angle = angle;

        world.createBody(this.bodydef);
        createFixture(fixtureDef);
        setType(bt);
    };
```

`Shape` has follow definition:

```
public abstract class Shape extends org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body{
    protected World world;
    protected BodyDef bodydef;

    public Shape(BodyDef bd, World w) {
        super(bd, w);

        this.world = w;
        this.bodydef = bd;
    }

    protected abstract void update();
    protected abstract void draw(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable);
}
```

In `Level.java` which extends `org.jbox2d.dynamics.World`
I create a `Rectangle` and call `Rectangle.draw(gLDrawable)`

```
new Rectangle(
        new Vec2(1.0f,1.0f),//Vec2(x,y)
        0.0f,   //angle
        2.0f,   //width
        2.0f,   //height
        BodyType.DYNAMIC,   //bodyType
        0.5f,   //density
        0.5f,   //friction
        0.5f,   //restitution
        this,               //world
        new BodyDef()));        //BodyDef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use `UserData` of `org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body`

Example:

```
org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body body = level.createBody(bodydef);
body.setUserData(
    new Shape(parameters)
);
```